# Overriding injected class from routing group in Slim 4?

Tags: php, slim, php-di, slim-4

I have a Slim4 Application composed of several modules separated in different routing groups, like so:

```
$app->group('/app', function(RouteCollectorProxy  $app) {
   /*blah blah*/
})->add(MyMiddleWare::class);

$app->group('/api', function(RouteCollectorProxy  $app) {
   /*blah blah*/
})->add(MyMiddleware::class);

$app->group('/admin', function(RouteCollectorProxy  $app) {
   /*blah blah*/
})->add(MyMiddleware::class);
```

MyMiddleware receives an **Interface**

```
class MyMiddleware
{
    public function __construct(IMyInterface $myServiceImplementingInterface) { /*blah blah*/ }
}
```

When we setup the container, we tell it which class to inject so PHP-DI know which class to construct the middleware with:

```
/* bootstraping */
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/container.php');
$container = $containerBuilder->build();
```

and

```
/*container.php*/
return [
    IMyInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
        return new MyServiceImplementingInterface();
    },
];
```

**My main question is:**

Would it be possible to somehow override the implementation of the container setup for `IMyInterface::class` based on the Routing Group ? so I could have something like:

Main container setup:

```
/*container.php*/
return [
    IMyInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
        return new MyServiceImplementingInterface();
    },
];
```

Specific route group container setup:

```
/*container.admin.php*/
return [
    IMyInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
        return new AnotherServiceImplementingInterface();
    },
];
```

Comment: As the DI container is registered with the App quite early on, I think you would have to decide what group it will go in and build the DI container accordingly.  This would potentially mean having to make sure this code is kept in line. See if any other suggestions come up.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I would suggest to avoid overriding the *definition* based on some condition (i.e which route group you're adding the middleware to), but instead add different implementations of the interface (i.e different middlewares implementing same interface) to different route groups. Something like `$app->group('/admin')->add(AdminMiddleware::class);` and `$app->group(ApiMiddeware::class);`

Comment: @Nima, so you can have different DI containers for different middleware classes?

Comment: @NigelRen Not different containers, but different definitions in the same container. So if one is going to have both `AdminMiddleware` and `ApiMiddleware`, then corresponding definitions for both class names should exist in the container. The user can explicitly define what should be passed to constructor of these two middlewares. There should be a definition in the container that uses `AdminService` to instantiate `AdminMiddleware` and an entry that uses `ApiService` to instantiate `ApiMiddleware`.

Comment: @Nima, if it solves OP's problem - then post it as an answer.  I've just started using Slim 4 and so I've not used it this way before.

Comment: @Nima this is probably the way to go, I'm just trying to test it in my current proeject to see if there's anything I'm not noticing about this approach. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using two different objects of `MyMiddleware` class for different groups, each constructed using appropriate implementation of `IMyInterface`. You can tell PHP-DI to call the constructor with the parameters you want.

Here I created two instances of `MyMiddleware`, one with the name `AdminMiddleware` and the other named `ApiMiddleware` in the container. using `DI\create()->constructor()` method, I configure the DI to inject different implementations of `IMyInterface` while building these two objects:

```
<?php

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

// this is the path of autoload.php relative to my index.php file
// change it according to your directory structure
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

interface IMyInterface {
    public function sampleMethod();
}

class MyServiceImplementingInterface implements IMyInterface {
    public function sampleMethod() {
        return 'This implementation is supposed to be used for API endpoint middleware';
    }
}

class AnotherServiceImplementingInterface implements IMyInterface {
    public function sampleMethod() {
        return 'This implementation is supposed to be used for Admin middleware';
    }
}

class MyMiddleware
{
    private $service;
    public function __construct(IMyInterface $myServiceImplementingInterface) { 
        $this->service = $myServiceImplementingInterface;
    }
    public function __invoke($request, $handler)
    {
        $response = $handler->handle($request);
        $response->getBody()->write($this->service->sampleMethod());
        return $response;
    }
}

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
    'AdminMiddleware' => DI\create(MyMiddleware::class)->constructor(DI\get(AnotherServiceImplementingInterface::class)),
    'ApiMiddleware' => DI\create(MyMiddleware::class)->constructor(DI\get(MyServiceImplementingInterface::class))
]);

$container = $containerBuilder->build();

AppFactory::setContainer($container);
$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->group('/admin', function($app) {
    $app->get('/dashboard', function($request, $response, $args){
        return $response;
    });
})->add($container->get('AdminMiddleware'));
$app->group('/api', function($app) {
    $app->get('/endpoint', function($request, $response, $args){
        return $response;
    });
})->add($container->get('ApiMiddleware'));

$app->run();
```